# Allow framing of links to current site in stack snippets

Tags: feature-request, security, stack-snippets, framing

Over at PPCG.SE (CodeGolf.SE), we regularly use stack snippets for leaderboards for our programming challenges. However, the snippets feature prevents our leaderboards from having links to the answers. However, upon clicking these links brings this error: `For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.`. Additionally, we cannot open the links in a new window.

**NOTE: after experimenting, I have found that some GitHub links work for framing, but not Stack Exchange ones, why is this?**

### Examples

```html
Stack Exchange does not work:
<a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com">meta.stackexchange.com</a>

<p>
  Google does not work:
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">www.google.com</a>

  <p>
    GitHub DOES work:
    <a href="http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=JFM9JHZpR2knLCBtRE5-REggcn0vbTRTbWVQIjg2NCI1">github.io</a>
```

Therefore, I propose to allow stack snippets to frame links from the same site (so in this case, all links from `codegolf.stackexchange.com`, but works the same for other sites), and/or allow snippets to open links in new windows from the same site. If this is not going to be implemented, does anyone know of a work around? Is there a reason why framing is not allowed?

Comment: Well, the core of the problem is the fact frames are being used. If SE will provide a way to view the results of a code snippet without a frame, you will be able to link to it and those problems will go away.